# Update statement on same table with multi column subsquery

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery

Everyone,  I have been working on a query for last one hour that I need to sort **country** field **alphabetically** and update its **sort_order**  field with **incremantal numbers**.

I wrote a select query which sorts my country field in alphabetic order and I added a row number. So far so good.

My select query response is :

```
    objid | country | sort_order | my_rownum
--------------------------------------------
    c1    | America | 0          | 1
    g2    | Englanc | 0          | 2
    k1    | France  | 0          | 3
```

Now, I need to update **my sort**_order field with **my_rownum** values.

Country_Info Table :

```
    objid | country | sort_order
----------------------------
    c1    | America | 0
    g2    | Englanc | 0
    k1    | France  | 0
```

After Update table must be like that :

```
        objid | country | sort_order
    ----------------------------
        c1    | America | 1
        g2    | Englanc | 2
        k1    | France  | 3
```

I tried many sql queries but something is wrong with my queries.

Sample pseudo query for explaining what I need. I can not merge the logic.

```
-- sort_order will set when sample query objid and counrty_info objid are equals

update country_info
set sort_order = (value from subquery here)
where (value equivlance from subquery for objid here) 

--Subquery 
(select c.objid, c.country, c.sort_order, row_number() over (partition by 1 order by 1) as my_rownumber
 from counrty c where <bla  bla> order by c.country asc)
```

Regards...

Comment: Can you share the query you tried that didn't work?

Comment: Check my pseudo code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you table name as table1, you can use merge clause like this:

```
MERGE INTO table1 t1
     USING (SELECT s.*, ROWNUM my_rownum
              FROM (  SELECT *
                        FROM table1
                    ORDER BY 3) s) t2
        ON (T1.objid = t2.objid)
WHEN MATCHED
THEN
   UPDATE SET T1.sort_order = t2.my_rownum
```

I hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

if using SQL2005 or later, try:

```
select *, sort_order = dense_rank() over (order by country)
from yourtable
```

This would give all occurrences of the first country `1`, all of the second `2`, and so on.  If you want unique sort values, use `row_number()`.

Comment: There is no such thing as SQL 2005. There is a SQL 2003 standard and a SQL 2006 standard, but no 2005 (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sql)